# An app with a translator

Tags: voice-recognition, language-translation

I have an idea for an app that requires a voice recognition translator. I want to be able to speak in a few select languages and have the app translate it in to English text on screen. I know apps like this already exist but mine has a special edge to it that makes it profitable.

Basically my question is... how do I get the coding for a translator? Is there one that is open source? Are there pre existing ones that I can pay a licensing fee for? What is the best way to get a voice translator without paying to have one built from scratch?

Comment: First, translation = written works, while interpretation = spoken... so you are looking for an interpretation engine...

Comment: So I need an voice interpreter that transfers over into a text translator? 
Does this have to be made from the ground up or are there cheaper solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the mobile platform you are writing for, voice capture and speech-to-text work differently. Check the docs for your specific platform.

To translate the text once you've captured it, the Microsoft Translator API gives you 2 million characters per month for free.